# Substituting a character in a string when certain conditions are met

Tags: python, regex

Say we want to replace **4**.
**1.** When the character has an alphabet **prior** and **post** its position.
*Example:* Cat24Bat**4**D : Cat24batD
**2.** When it occurs at the end of the string and has an alphabet prior to it.
*Example:* Cat24Bat**4** : Cat24Bat
Python, Regular Expressions

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(?<=[A-Za-z])\d(?=[A-Za-z]|\Z)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tridNS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` to find all combination of a alphabet followed by 1 and then replace it with the found alphabet

```
>>> s = 'Cat1Bat21Hat1' 
>>> re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])1(?=[a-zA-Z]|$)', r'\1', s)
'CatBat21Hat'
```

Comment: this regex fails for `Cat12Bat21Hat1`

Comment: Thanks a ton Sunitha. I was wondering if you would suggest how to add the following feature: 
'Cat13Bat1' 
Result: 'Cat13Bat'

Comment: @Debarpan898. Sorry I misread the question. Updated the answer

Comment: @Sunitha. No Problem. It's working fine now. Thank you!